# Androidthings starter kit multitouch screen flickering

Tags: screen, flicker, android-things

Hey guys I am new to Androidthings and I have been setup my androidthings kit. So far so good. Everything looks good while booting. I can see the linux logo. But as soon as it goes to the main screen (dashboard) it starts flickering.

When I press upon the white connector on the board, I can see the screen without any problems. But as soon as I remove the pressure, it starts acting up. I have tried to place it correctly several times but it's the same issue everytime.

Anyone else have the same issue? I am using normal power socket.

https://plus.google.com/u/1/117703851833000451694/posts/Ja2ybKwHX5V

Comment: Check board-display electric connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the developer preview BSP that was patched in v1.0

Update your board with the latest version of Android Things using the [i.MX7D flashing instructions](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d) and your display should work correctly.